# Wireless connection lost after few minutes

Tags: wireless

WiFi works on other devices but just not with my new laptop. It seems like I get a connection after rebooting, but once I lose it, I always have to reboot to get connection. Here is the info I got from running this script from a previous post.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10498356/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix your issue or not, but disabling IPv6 and changing the channel on your router may help. In the log, it says at the bottom that it keeps timing out. It also says it's configuring IPV6 around that time.

Further up on that log it says that channel 6 has 15 APs on it. You might consider using something less common, channel 4 looks good. Here is the relevant part...

Channel occupancy:

```
  8   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
  15   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  3   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
  7   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` will fix this issue after a reboot in most cases

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13119513#post13119513